# sqldf select values from other table

Tags: r, sqldf

Dear stackoverflow experts,

I have two tables

```
table1<-read.table("table1.txt",header=TRUE)
table2<-read.table("table2.txt",header=TRUE)
```

I want to select from table 1 all of the values that match values of the first column of table 2. I have try sqldf, but I´m not sure of the syntax,

```
selection<-sqldf("SELECT *, column1 from table1 WHERE column1 like column2 from table2")
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: It appears you are looking for some kind of join. There are many examples in the help for `sqldf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
 table1[sapply(table1, function(x) x %in% table2[, 1, drop=FALSE])]
```

---

What happens here is that the `sapply` statement is returning a logical list indicating which elements of `table1` are in `table2`'s first column.   We are then using that logical vector to index `table1`

```
  # to see this more clearly, try the following line, 
  # which is what is being used to index table1
  sapply(table1, function(x) x %in% table2[, 1, drop=FALSE])
```

Answer (score 3):

A left join is what you are after.

```
 selection <- sqldf('select * from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.column1 = table2.column1')
```

Or you could use `merge`

```
merged <- merge(table1, table2, by = 'column1')
```

Comment: Although I believe that merge would be an INNER JOIN unless you specified `all.x=TRUE`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to select all values from `table1` that match values from the first column of `table2` *without* sqldf:

```
table1[table1 %in% table2[,1]]
```

I am not sure if this is what you meant, but this is what your question implies to me. If you want to select values from `table1` that match the values of the *corresponding row* of `table2`, use

```
table1[table1 == table2[,1]]
```

If you just want to consider a single column from `table1`, use something like

```
table1[table1[,1] %in% table2[,1], 1]
```